Does the inner loop run first?
I am trying to understand the order of nested loops. The first loop through the outer loop returns
13 16 19 113 116 119

It looks like it starts with the outer loop first then fully goes through the inner loop iterations and back to outer loop until iterations, is that correct?
Is this the case for most nested loops?
i1 = 1
while i1 < 19:
    i2 = 3
    while i2 <= 9:
        print(f'{i1}{i2}', end=' ')
        i2 = i2 + 3
    i1 = i1 + 10

When I went through the 2nd iteration of the outer loop i2 overwrites back to 3 (instead of 6) which is what is confusing me and is incorrect.

See it step by step at http://pythontutor.com…

This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with using a debugger.  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?

So you're expecting the statement i2 = 3 to assign a value of 6 (rather than 3) on the second iteration of the outer loop?   WHY???

There appear to be some indentation issues here. Please [edit] accordingly.

Another possible source of misunderstanding - you describe 13 16 19 113 116 119 as being the "first loop through the outer loop", but in fact that is two outer loop iterations.  The output would be vastly clearer if you put some separator between i1 and i2, so that you can tell which digits are coming from which variable.

To simply resolve such questions just put in print statements such as print('inner') within the inner loop and print('outer') or print the current values of variables where that is useful.

Yes, you are correct about the order of execution in nested loops. The outer loop will iterate first, and for each iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop will complete all its iterations before moving to the next iteration of the outer loop.

How does that square with being surprised that i2 gets reset to 3?

Thanks this helps a lot. Still in school must have misread that the inner loop completes first. It was only making sense to me that their one or the other had to full run its course before the other.

That would only happen if one loop is AFTER the other. But in your code one loop is INSIDE the other
